# chroot and connmanctl

Tags: debian, networking, chroot, d-bus

I have an embedded device which has an embedded linux running on it through cross compilation through BUILDROOT.

Additionally, I have also a debian installation on it which is invked using a script as follows:

```
mount -o bind /dev /debian/dev
mount -o bind /lib/modules /debian/lib/modules
chroot /debian chroot_init
```

Now what I was trying to do was configure wifi access under debian and I was trying to use the `connmanctl` utility but got the following error:

```
Error: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

So, I thought ok somehow dbus is not running and I tried to start it by:

```
systemctl start dbus
```

but I got the message:

```
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
```

I am not sure really what to do next. I am guessing this is because I am running debian under this chroot environment. Is there any workaround for this? How can I get the networking capabilities under this debian installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the simplest to configure the networking in your embedded system before entering the chroot.

Comment: Yeah, and then I used the dhclient to share the connection. seems to work.